# Why DTLSv1_listen() returns zero?

Tags: ssl, openssl, dtls

I am learning DTLS using the sample code "dtls_udp_echo.c"...

Server: "DTLSv1_listen(ssl, &client_addr)"

The underlying socket is non-blocking but will wake up upon readability.

As soon as client does SSL_connect(), server gets invoked. So I believe hello is transmitted and received by the server. But DTLSv1_listen() always return zero, and client_addr is all zero as well. I just don't get it what could be wrong.

I take the suggestion of related post to add SSL_state_string_long(). It prints "SSL state before/accept initialization" after DTLSv1_listen() returns 0.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you enabled cookie exchange? I'm not sure if it is enabled by default in newer openssl versions. To prevent the server from dos attacks, there is a different behavior for hello messages. The client sends a hello, the server answers with an helloVerifyRequest. The client sends an hello with attached cookie. The server verify this cookie and when it is valid, the normal handshake routine continues. the DTLSv1_listen returns 0 after sending this HelloVerifyRequest. May thats your problem. I found a nearly perfect documentation about client server communication with dtls. here is the [link](http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/DTLS.pdf).